# Can I setup a PS3 to use a PS4 Dual Shock 4 controller without a PS3 controller?

Tags: ps3, controllers

So I just bought a PS3 Slim but it did not come with a controller. I couldn't find any PS3 controllers so I got a Dual Shock 4 instead.

Is there any way I can use the Dual Shock 4 with the PS3 console without a PS3 controller?

*(I'm a Xbox user so I don't know much about this.)*

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, you can also use a DualShock 4 wirelessly with a PS3.**

From [Eurogamer - How to use a DualShock 4 wirelessly with a PS3](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2014-07-02-how-to-use-a-dualshock-4-wirelessly-with-a-ps3)

> Here are the steps:
>
> - Plug in DualShock 4 controller via USB.
> - Go to Accessory Settings and Manage Bluetooth Devices.
> - Scan for Bluetooth Device.
> - Unplug the DualShock 4, press Share and PS Buttons.
> - Once device is found, plug the DualShock 4 back in and select Wireless Controller.

Congratulations! You now have a rumble-free DualShock 4 working with your PS3!

Comment: See the problem for me is, I don't have a ps3 controller, and when i start my ps3 its on the screen where it asks if my HDMI can play audio too. But I need to press the PS button to press X, and I cant do that because it doesn't work

Comment: Have you plugged the PS4 controller in with a USB cable as the answer says to do ?

Comment: Remember to use quotation formatting when you are directly quoting them.

Comment: "Have you plugged the PS4 controller in with a USB cable as the answer says to do ?" yes I did plug it in with a usb but it says in order to use controller i must press PS button.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, it is possible.** According to [Business Insider](https://www.businessinsider.com/do-ps4-controllers-work-on-ps3) you can plug a PS4 controller into a PS3 with this method:

> To use a PlayStation 4 controller with a PlayStation 3 console, the
> easiest approach is to simply connect the controller using a USB
> cable. Once the cable is connecting the two pieces of hardware, you'll
> be able to play PS3 games with the controller right away.

Just keep in mind that there may be a few backwards compatibility issues when connecting the accessory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It is possible and according to [the gaming kit](https://thegamingkit.com/can-you-use-a-ps3-controller-on-ps4/), you can use PS4 controller with PS3.
But always remember that there can be compatibility issues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).